# JPA reference parent table from child in @JoinColumn

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities

```java
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Parent {
  private String other_id; 
}
```

```java
public class Child extends Parent { 
}
```

```java
public class Other {
  private String id;
}
```

I want to access entity Other from Child, but I cant edit Parent.

So I want something like

```java
public class Child extends Parent { 
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "other_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Other other;
}
```

But this throws "Invalid column name 'other_id'." And I can see that the query generated tries to fetch child.other_id. I also tried using @SecondaryTable

```java
@SecondaryTable(name = "parent")
public class Child extends Parent { 
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "other_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "parent")
  private Other other;
}
```

But then when starting the application it immediately throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered 'subclass table index' [-1] was outside expected range ( [0] < i < [5] )
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.associateSubclassNamesToSubclassTableIndex(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.associateSubclassNamesToSubclassTableIndexes(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:681)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.processPersistentClassHierarchy(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:657)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.processPersistentClassHierarchy(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.buildSubclassNamesBySubclassTableMapping(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:621)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:561)
```

Is this a bug? is there some other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why on the second attempt did you also try to add the @SecondaryTable annotation? JPA join inheritance automatically has the Child table be a secondary table to the parent table - try removing your SecondaryTable annotation, and also mark the relationship's join column with insertable=false, updatable=false so that JPA knows the column is still controlled only by the parent.other_id String property